# Can't build Electron app for Windows

Tags: electron, wine

I have problem with builind Electron app for Windows on Mac OS. Yesterday I could do that, today I can't. I have error:
`Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v1.6.1
Could not find "wine" on your system.`
I've installed Wine and have also CrossOver. Only things that are change from yesterday is that I've installed Android Studio, NativeScript and new version of Java SE.